# hive array posexplode issue

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hi I have a scenario using hive array explode

I have a hive table with multiple arrays (4 arrays)

```
desc manager;
OK
supervisorid            int                                         
reportee_name           array<string>                               
reportee_age            array<string>                               
reportee_address        array<string>                               
reportee_occupation     array<string>                               
reportee_salary         array<string>
```

the above 4 arrays are dependent (like the nth element of each array is mapped to nth element of other arrays.

But there are some scenarios where i may get no values for a n element of a particluar array when other dependent array's n element has values.
Example

```
select * from manager;
OK
101 ["richie","tom","jack"] ["36","28","29"]    ["abc","xyz"]   ["SE","JSE","SE"]   ["5000","3000","6000"]
```

when all array columns reportee_name,reportee_age,reportee_occupation,reportee_salary has 3 elemnts while reportee_address has only 2 elemnts

So when i do posexplode lateral view i will be getting only the 2 elements

```
select supervisorid,reportee_name_val,reportee_age_val,reportee_address_val,reportee_occupation_val,reportee_salary_val from manager lateral view posexplode(reportee_name)reportee_name  as reportee_name_pos,reportee_name_val lateral view posexplode(reportee_age)reportee_age as reportee_age_pos,reportee_age_val lateral view posexplode (reportee_address)reportee_address as reportee_address_pos,reportee_address_val lateral view posexplode (reportee_occupation)reportee_occupation as reportee_occupation_pos,reportee_occupation_val lateral view posexplode(reportee_salary)reportee_salary as reportee_salary_pos,reportee_salary_val where reportee_name_pos<=>reportee_age_pos and reportee_age_pos<=>reportee_address_pos and reportee_address_pos<=>reportee_occupation_pos and reportee_occupation_pos<=>reportee_salary_pos; 
OK
101 richie  36  abc SE  5000
101 tom 28  xyz JSE 3000
Time taken: 0.175 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

In the above query,if i remove the position equals condition ( reportee_occupation_pos<=>reportee_salary_pos),the result will be cartesian.

The expected output is

```
101,richie,36,abc,SE,5000
101,tom,28,xyz,JSE,3000
101,jack,29,NULL,SE
```

The output got from the below query

```
select supervisorid,reportee_name_val,reportee_age_val,reportee_address_val,reportee_occupation_val,reportee_salary_val from manager lateral view posexplode(reportee_name)reportee_name  as reportee_name_pos,reportee_name_val lateral view posexplode(reportee_age)reportee_age as reportee_age_pos,reportee_age_val lateral view posexplode (reportee_address)reportee_address as reportee_address_pos,reportee_address_val lateral view posexplode (reportee_occupation)reportee_occupation as reportee_occupation_pos,reportee_occupation_val lateral view posexplode(reportee_salary)reportee_salary as reportee_salary_pos,reportee_salary_val where reportee_name_pos<=>reportee_age_pos and reportee_age_pos<=>reportee_address_pos and reportee_address_pos<=>reportee_occupation_pos and reportee_occupation_pos<=>reportee_salary_pos;


101,richie,36,abc,SE,5000
101,tom,28,xyz,JSE,3000
```

I am expecting all the elements of each array and if any array has lesser no of elements it should come as NULL in the lateral view

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: if your missing n element is not the last one, by definition, then your data is corrupted. A slightly better way would be to use NULL as a placeholder for a missing element better than that would be to use array of structs instead of multiple arrays and much better way would be to normalize the data and create additional table instead of arrays

Comment: is it possible to add NULL to array having less no of elements dynamically in the hive script

Comment: This is a really bad data modeling. I would strongly recommend to use another option.